# How to get an HBITMAP of one image from an array of images from a resource?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a resource that has an id `ID_IMAGES` which is a PNG file.  This resource is an array of images, all the same size (16x16).  I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to pull out any one of these images and generate an `HBITMAP` from it.

I've looked around on the net, but I cannot find any info.  Perhaps I'm using the wrong keywords?

Comment: If you only want to draw a subimage and not necessarily extract it, the [image list API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389.aspx) looks appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Looks like these are not really meant for PNG image list.  More for use with icons.

Comment: Indeed, the image list API allows to extract icons but not bitmaps. But if all you need is to draw, you could use e.g. GDI+ to read your PNG data, and rely on the API to draw subimages.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, but as I am not the drawer of the images, this won't work.  I have to pass an HBITMAP to an API, which then uses that to draw the image.

Comment: The standard Windows resource formats don't support PNG files, nor do they support arrays. Any solution is going to be specific to the particular way you've stored the PNG files in the resource data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [CImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx) class. Its [`Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/tf4bytf8.aspx) method can load a stream of data. CImage supports PNG format. Basically, you load the image from your resource and then use its [`Detach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kfsc7wz.aspx) method to get your HBITMAP

Comment: Hmmm, looks like `CImage::PlgBlt()` would at least allow me to copy an indexed item to another `HBITMAP`.  Thanks.